# Duplicated factory error with rspec and factory girl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2, factory-bot

I'm trying to reset the "sequence" in factory girl between each test I run.

(`factory_girl 2.6.0` and `factory_girl_rails 1.7.0`)

I think that to do so, I have to reload the FactoryGirl definitions. I do it in the last lines of spec_helper.rb:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'
#uncomment the following line to use spork with the debugger
#require 'spork/ext/ruby-debug'

Spork.prefork do
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'rspec/autorun'
  require 'capybara/rspec'

  require "rails/application"
  Spork.trap_method(Rails::Application::RoutesReloader, :reload!)

  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.mock_with :rspec

    require 'database_cleaner'
    config.before(:suite) do
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
      DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
    end

    config.before(:each) do
      DatabaseCleaner.start
    end

    config.after(:each) do
      DatabaseCleaner.clean
    end

    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

    # For mailer
    config.include(MailerMacros)
    config.before(:each) {reset_email}
  end

end

Spork.each_run do
  # This code will be run each time you run your specs.
  I18n.backend.reload!
  Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
  require 'factory_girl'
  FactoryGirl.definition_file_paths = [File.join(Rails.root, 'spec', 'factories')]
  FactoryGirl.find_definitions
end
```

Adding:

```
  FactoryGirl.definition_file_paths = [File.join(Rails.root, 'spec', 'factories')]
  FactoryGirl.find_definitions
```

Leads me to the following error when running `rspec spec/`

```
→ bundle exec guard
Guard uses Growl to send notifications.
Guard is now watching at '/Rails/projects/MyRailsProject'
Starting Spork for RSpec
Using RSpec
Preloading Rails environment
Loading Spork.prefork block...
Spork is ready and listening on 8989!
Spork server for RSpec successfully started
Guard::RSpec is running, with RSpec 2!
Running all specs
Exception encountered: #<FactoryGirl::DuplicateDefinitionError: Factory already registered: user>
```

Which seems to be a duplicated factory error, maybe it's trying to load factory girl twice, but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is trying to load all your factories twice, because you're asking it to. 
Replace your call to `find_definitions` with

```
FactoryGirl.reload
```

which clear out existing factories, sequences etc and then call `find_definitions` for you